# UIRefreshControl( pull left to right refresh ) concept in UICollectionView horizontally

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, horizontalscrollview, pull-to-refresh

I have a custom horizontal collection view that has 1 row and I want to add pull to refresh functionality which, by default, appears above my row of cells. I would like the user to be able to pull the collection view from left to right to activate the UIRefreshControl. Any ideas?

Comment: use gestures it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
     CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
     CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
     UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
     float y = offset.x + bounds.size.width - inset.right;
     float h = size.width;


    float reload_distance = 75; //distance for which you want to load more
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
     // write your code getting the more data
       NSLog(@"load more rows");

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Updated Nitin's answer for Swift 5.0

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
            let bounds = scrollView.bounds
            let size = scrollView.contentSize
            let inset = scrollView.contentInset
            let y = offset.x + bounds.size.width - inset.right
            let h = size.width
            
            let reload_distance = 75 //distance for which you want to load more
            if y > h + CGFloat(reload_distance) {
                //reload
                reload()
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this http://code4app.net/ios/RefreshView/5247b46b6803fa7304000000.it is used to refresh the view ,in the same manner u can refresh the collectionView.

Comment: The link doesn't work. can you provide an updated link please?

Comment: @QamarSuleiman https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl this repo may help you:)