# How do I add a refresh control to a horizontal collectionview in a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I currently have:

```
        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.postsView.addSubview(refresher)
```

inside the viewdidload() of the viewcontroller containing the collectionview. Interacting with the collectionview and getting custom cells to appear works flawlessly. However, when I add this refresher, it does not do anything. I'm not sure as to why, am i missing a step here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Does it show up at all? or does it just not do anything. Are there any errors? Have you checked that your "refresh" function works. And more commonly is it added a subView of your collectionView? (which it should be).

Comment: no errors, it doesn't show up, nor does it do anything when I swipe to the right(if i was viewing the first cell starting from the left). Also "postsView" is the name given to the collection view.

Comment: hey @user100002 so the refresher actually appears on top of the UICollectionview, not to the left. Any clue as to why this is happening? I have horizontal bounce as well as horizontal scrolling. But when i turned on vertical bounce and pulled down the refresher was right there.

Answer (score -1):

Implement the UIScrollview delegate and please give the below code a try

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
     CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
     CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
     UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
     float y = offset.x + bounds.size.width - inset.right;
     float h = size.width;


     float reload_distance = 75; //distance for which you want to load more
     if(y > h + reload_distance) {
        // write your code getting the more data
        NSLog(@"load more rows");

     }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803279/2395636). Also this is not in `Swift`.